# Physical interpretation of zero-mode in Free boson CFT?

Tags: conformal-field-theory

In chapter 6.3 of the "yellow book" (Di Francesco, Mathieu, & Sénéchal), one get a zero-mode from expanding the Hamiltonian of free boson theory. It is not difficult to figure out the physical meaning of $a_n$ and $\bar{a}_n$ being the "right-moving" and "left-moving" excitation creation or annihilation operators. It seems the zero-mode here corresponds to the Casimir energy term (e.g. changing system from complex plane to cylinder, the anomalous term in energy-momentum tensor). It is not so obvious to me why this is the case. It would be appreciated if anyone could help me get a more intuitive interpretation of zero-mode in this case. In addition, in chapter 10.2, the line above (10.29), i.e. $\frac{\sqrt{A}}{\mid \omega_1 \mid}=\sqrt{\tau_2}$, could anyone enlighten me on this proof?

P.S. $\sqrt{A}$ is the normalised zero-mode in free boson field $\phi$, $\omega_1 \& \omega_2$ are the periods of the torus, while $\tau = \frac{\omega_1}{\omega_2} = \tau_1 + i \tau_2$. In (10.29), there is also a typo, i.e. $G^{\prime}(0)=-2\ln{(\sqrt{A} \sqrt{\tau_2} \mid \eta(\tau) \mid^2)}$

Comment: It's currently unclear what exactly this question is asking without having access to the book you are referencing. Please include enough context so one can tell what you are talking about without opening the book, in particular define notation used (what are $A,\omega_1,\tau_2$?) and write down equation (10.29).

Comment: The book is [this one](https://books.google.it/books?id=5u7jBwAAQBAJ&dq=di+francesco+mathieu&hl=en).

Comment: The book has been provided. And the question itself is irrelevant with (10.29). I'm confused with the line above.